# "error: expected primary-expression before '<=' token" What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

So here is my code. Honestly, I started learning C++ about ten days ago, and have just started if statements. Sorry in advance if my syntax is terrible.

```
#include<iostream>


float bmi(float, float);

int main(){

    float weight, height;

    std::cout << "Input your weight(In pounds)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> weight;
    std::cout << "Input your height(In inches)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> height;

    bmi(weight, height);

    return 0;
}

float bmi(float n1,float n2){
    float bmin;
    bmin = (n1*703)/(n2*n2);
    std::cout << "Your BMI is: " << bmin << std::endl;

    if(bmin <= 18.49){
        std::cout << "You are underweight!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(bmin >=18.5 and <= 25){
        std::cout << "You have normal weight!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(bmin >=25.01 and <=29.99){
        std::cout << "You are overweight." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (bmin >=30){
        std::cout << "You are obese..."
    }
}
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is wrong here.
Oh, and here's the error.
 The error is on lines 23 and 26.

```
C:\Users\Finnegan\Desktop\Computer Science 3-4\Computer Science\fm2-
2.cpp|23|error: expected primary-expression before '<=' token|
```

Then I have an error on line 31 which is

```
C:\Users\Finnegan\Desktop\Computer Science 3-4\Computer Science\fm2-

2.cpp|31|error: expected ';' before '}' token|
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `bmin >=18.5 and <= 25` Can't do this. Use `bmin >=18.5 and bmin <= 25` instead.

Comment: I hope you weren't planning on posting a question on stackoverflow.com every time your C++ program doesn't compile and you can't figure out why. It will take you many, many years to learn C++ this way.

Comment: Where is the return of the function `bmi`?

Comment: Not sure what that difference was @user4581301.

Comment: @Raindrop7 It has a std::cout in it. Multiple times. Didn't you see that?

Comment: The difference is that one is valid C++, and the other one isn't.

Comment: So then make it return `void`.

Comment: @Finnegan whar Raindrop means is `float bmi(float n1,float n2)` declares that it returns a `float`. The compiler will generate a program based on a `float` being returned. There is no `return` statement in the function, so the function is broken and the program will not work. It might LOOK like it works, but it doesn't and sooner or later it will get you.

Comment: Ah, okay. That actually makes sense.

Comment: Changed it, and now it _definitely_ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in this else statement (and in other similar )

```
else if(bmin >=18.5 and <= 25){
```

is equivalent to

```
else if( ( bmin >=18.5 ) and ( <= 25 )){
```

So the compiler issues an error because instead of the construction `<= 25` it expects a valid expression.

It is evident that you mean

```
else if(bmin >=18.5 and bmin <= 25){
```

Take into account that the function `bmi` has return type float but returns nothing.

```
float *bmi*(float n1,float n2);
```

And in this statement you forgot to place a semicolon.

```
else if (bmin >=30){
    std::cout << "You are obese..."
                                   ^^^
```

Comment: @Raindrop7 The compiler provides alternative tokens according to the C++ Standard. See "2.5 Alternative tokens" in the C++ Standard.

Comment: Disagree with your first "is equivalent to"  - the only equivalence is that they are both syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

You want to explicitly indicate `bmin <= 25` instead of saying `<=25` without a subject

```
    if(bmin <= 18.49){
        std::cout << "You are underweight!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(bmin >=18.5 and bmin <= 25){
        std::cout << "You have normal weight!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(bmin >=25.01 and bmin <=29.99){
        std::cout << "You are overweight." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (bmin >=30){
        std::cout << "You are obese..."
    }
```